# cakePHP Blog error messages

Tags: php, blogs, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to set up a cakePHP blog. Following the steps at:

http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/building_a_blog_with_cakephp_part_1_getting_started.html

but when I get to the stage of creating 'article.ctp' in order to view the 'Read More' part of the blog. I get the following error messages:

Notice (8): Undefined index: id = 1 [CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 2519]

Notice (8): Undefined index: id = 1 [CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 2495]

Notice (8): Undefined variable: articles [APP/View/Blog/article.ctp, line 1]

Sadly this is hosted on my test server locally in MAMP so I can't show you the live error I am getting. But just thought id check and see if anyone has had similar issues with this (I believe its a common beginner tutorial for learning to use cakePHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an ancient tutorial, try out the cakephp 2.x blog tutorial from the official site:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html

And your error is quite simple, the variable `$articles` does not exist in your view, so you haven't set the variable in your controller with `$this->set('articles', 'value');`

Comment: Thanks man, I did come across a few errors in that tutorial but managed to correct them. Hopefully your tutorial works better for me :)